# How to create data tables in angular

Tags: angular, datatables

I have a datatable.net knowing that I have downloaded All libraries, but it shows me that there is no data and the data appears at the top of the table as in the picture
who encountered this problem Please help me and thanks

[image]

```ts
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = './assets/datatables-init.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

```html
<table id="dataTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <th scope="row">{{item.code}}</th>
      <td>{{item.barCode}}</td>
      <td>{{item.sn}}</td>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a table inside an angular component, create a component `data-table.component.ts` this to store/fetch data object

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface UserData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
})
export class DataTableComponent {
  users: UserData[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@example.com' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Jane Smith', email: 'jane@example.com' },
  ];
}
```

And use this object in `data-table.component.html` to render it

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
      <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can find more about the angular project structure [here](https://angular.io/start)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should not manually insert elements and scripts with javascript when you are in an Angular project.  Angular needs to have full control of your webapp.

The answer by @bk7159 is correct for simple data tables, that is absolutely they way to go.  If you need more complex data tables then something like this might be the way to go: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables